# Python Amazon Boto S3 ongoing_restore bug

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using the Boto s3 package to view all the contents of my bucket.  If i do something like this

```
bucket = s3.get_bucket('my_bucket_name')
for k in bucket:
  print k.ongoing_restore
```

The snippet above outputs None for all objects.  However if i get a specific key using:

```
k = bucket.get_key('my_key')
k.ongoing_restore
```

then i get an output of True.  For some reason the value is not set properly in the first set of code and can't figure out why.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your situation.

You can normally debug objects by using `.__dict__`.

Here's my output:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3=boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = s3.get_bucket('my-bucket')
>>> for k in bucket:
...   print k.ongoing_restore
... 
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
>>> k = bucket.get_key('foo.zip')
>>> k.ongoing_restore
>>> k.__dict__
{'content_length': '234', 'encrypted': None, 'resp': None, 'ongoing_restore': None, 'source_version_id': None, 'content_language': None, '_storage_class': None, 'owner': None, 'filename': None, 'size': 234, 'delete_marker': False, 'etag': '"..."', 'content_encoding': None, 'content_md5': None, 'content_disposition': None, 'cache_control': None, 'metadata': {}, 'expires': None, 'version_id': None, 'x_robots_tag': None, 'last_modified': 'Sun, 06 Aug 2017 03:23:22 GMT', 'content_type': 'application/json', 'date': 'Mon, 28 Aug 2017 22:40:25 GMT', 'path': None, 'is_latest': False, 'local_hashes': {}, 'name': 'foo.zip', 'bucket': <Bucket: my-bucket>, 'expiry_date': None, 'mode': None}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

By using get_key, it is working (as mentioned in the below snippet)

```
   conn = get_s3_conn()
   print conn
   buc = get_bucket(conn, buc_name)
   print buc
   for key in buc.list(prefix='class-recordings/'):
       print '----'
       print key.ongoing_restore  #prints None
       k = buc.get_key(key)
       print k.ongoing_restore  #prints True
```